# How do I save a file in an IO::Handle?

Tags: perl

I'm a little confused on how to save a file that is an IO::Handle.

Here is what I have

```
    use IO::File;
    my $iof = IO::File->new;

    # open file
    $iof->open($path, "w") || die "$! : $path";  

    # ensure binary
    $iof->binmode;

    # output file to disk
    print $iof $self->File_Upload;
    $iof->close;
```

File_Upload is the IO::Handle given to me via the CGI module for a file upload, but the output in the file is...

```
IO::Handle=GLOB(0x20dabec)
```

Not the binary data of the uploaded PDF.

If I have a file in a file handle how do I save it?

Do I need IO::File if I have an IO::Handle?

Your input is appreciated.

1DMF

Comment: IO::File is simply a subclass of IO::Handle that provides seeking methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read from the `CGI` provided file handle using [`readline`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html):

```
print $iof readline($self->File_Upload);
```

The fact that your output contents were `'IO::Handle=GLOB(0x20dabec)'` implied that the `$self->File_Upload` is of type [`IO::Handle`](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Handle.html) and should be treated as such.

Using `readline` in a list context pulls all the lines as demonstrated above.  Alternatively, you could use the object method `->getlines()`:

```
print $iof $self->File_Upload->getlines();
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for, not sure how I missed this method. I blame it on being late on a Friday afternoon :0)

Answer (score 1):

How does one slurp a file?

```
my $fh = $self->File_Upload();
my $file = do { local $/; <$fh> };
```

Yes, this works for IO::Handle objects in addition to the usual globs (`STDIN`), references to globs (from `open my $fh, ...`) and IO scalars (`*STDIN{IO}`).

Then to print it,

```
print($iof $file);
```

In this particular case, you could simply use

```
print($iof $self->File_Upload()->getlines());
```

Comment: The output filehandle $iof should be opened with the `':raw'` layer if $fh contains binary data.

Comment: @Kaoru, He uses `binmode` to achieve the same result.

Comment: Oh I see that in the Question now, sorry :)